# How can I get the font size and font name of a UILabel?

Tags: ios

I have a UILabel which I set a font size and a font name with Interface Builder.  Now I have to read the values of both in my ViewController.

How can I do this?

Comment: This method has been deprecated iOS7, take a look at this article
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128797/calculating-uilabel-text-size

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Add a property to your view controller's .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

Link the label to this IBOutlet under "File's Owner" outlets in Interface Builder. If not using ARC, make sure you release it in -dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.label release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Then to get the font name and size all you need is

```
NSString *fontName = self.label.font.fontName;
CGFloat fontSize = self.label.font.pointSize;
```

Comment: Does not work. I can write text in it, but the fontName and pointSize is null.

Comment: Do you mean that you can programmatically change the text of the label, but you can't access the fontName and pointSize? I edited the above answer to include self.label, instead of just label, since I didn't mention creating an instance variable for label.

Comment: Also, make sure you've hooked up the label in Interface Builder with the IBOutlet you made in File's Owner (the view controller).

Comment: Ah, I forgot the connection in IB with the File's Owner.

Answer (score 37):

Swift:

```
var currentFontSize = button.titleLabel?.font.pointSize
```

Comment: They could have named it `font.size` whats up with `pointSize`. When you are creating font you use `size` `UIFont(name: ..., size: ...)`

Answer (score 16):

Pointsize value is not the Font Size of used in UIFont size property. Say if you go set interface builder font size to 14 and do a print of the pointSize you'll get only 11.

Comment: Seems to be working now. If i set the font size of a label in the interface builder / storyboard editor to 17... `myLabel.font.pointSize` returns 17.

Answer (score 2):

you have to attach it to a UILabel IBOutlet, and then, label.font...