# How to find which character is truncating in UITextView (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a textview which will be displaying four lines of text. If the text is too long, I need to show "See more" at the end of the fourth line. If text is small, I shouldn't show the "See more". I searched a lot, nothing helping me[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you have to use an NSTextContainer.
You can do some pretty fancy stuff with this, such as forming your text in a circle, triangle, or whatever UIBezierPath you can think of...

Here's apple's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nstextcontainer

You could then make a UIBezierPath shaped like this:[image]

In the bottom right corner, you could have your "See more" button.

If the text is too big (see lineBreakMode), then enable the button with

`seeMoreButton.enabled = true`

If the text fits, use

`seeMoreButton.enabled = false`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the full Text Kit stack and lay the text out yourself. Apple explained how to do this for text truncation in [a WWDC video](http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/220) a couple of years ago.

Comment: [Actual WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/220/) is here!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is have a max character count for the label and take the text up to that count and append with the "... See more" text like:

```
label.text = randomPost.text.substring(0, maxChars) + "... See more"
```

Note that I'm going off memory on how to substring in Swift, the signature I've provided may be off, just trying to convey the idea.

Comment: How do I know maxChars for different devices?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193520/determine-the-maximum-number-of-characters-a-uilabel-can-take) will give you maximum number of characters a UILabel can take!

Comment: @venky that's a different question. There's different ways to find out what device you're using.