# How to get Range value of text in a UITextView from tapped location?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsrange

I have a `UITextView` with some content of text. I need to get the exact range value of character/string from tapped location. I set `TapGestureRecognizer` for UITextView. In its action method i need to get the Range of tapped location. How its possible? I tested with some answers from Stackoverflow but they were not perfect. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the `UITextView` documentation?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/selectedRange

You can use this `selectedRange` method to determine the range of text that is selected by the user.

*Late edit: this was just recently downvoted, and gave me a chance to re-read my answer and I'd downvote my answer from 3 years ago too.*

**Updated answer:**

If there is a single tap, the tap action itself should have the info you need. At the core here, you'll need the UITouch events themselves, such as to calculate where the touch occurred in relation to where your text should be. This will let you know what part of text was covered by the user's finger.

I'm honestly not sure if any 3rd party solutions exist for this, but I'd bet [cocoapods.org](https://cocoapods.org/) would be a good place to start with keyword `UITextView tap`, if not [Github](https://github.com/) itself with keywords: `cocoapod uitextview`.

If I were implementing such a solution, with UITouch events in hand, using the properties described in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch) I'd use `The location of the touch within the view or window`
 given by the class.

By manipulating on one hand `CGPoints` from: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618116-location, you can then use String mechanisms for determining size of text in your given font.

While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128797/calculating-uilabel-text-size) solution is for a `UILabel`, it can either:

(a) be used in a different way but hopefully quite similarly in a UITextView

OR

(b) I have seen a dummy `UILabel` get used simply to calculate text sizes in features requiring this kind of precision. This is usually quite effective, since changing the string of a `UILabel` isn't expensive and a `UILabel` has built in properties for size calculation based on text and font without needing to do a layout pass.

Again, apologies if the first original answer seemed sassy, it does come off that way I see now. I will confirm, though, that my original answer still stands (the `selectedRange` mechanism) SHOULD the desired solution be in terms of a long press. For a custom solution based on a single touch down event, though, collecting `UITouch` events through a delegate callback and then processing those with knowledge of what `String` is present is the best approach from what I can tell.

Comment: We wont get selected Range from single tap. I need range from single tap instead of selecting a text from textview by double tap.

Comment: What do you mean range from single tap? Range from where to where if it's only being tapped once?

Comment: To whomever downvoted, thank you. It might seem like you just disliked something, but that actually prompted me to read this over and reexamine my answer, and ultimately let me update my answer with a much more detailed walk through. To whomever was watching, I hope the answer helps, and please comment any clarifications I can still add! :)