# Fix text in a table view cell, ios?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

In my table view I have made a custom cell as below image

Custom Cell

[image: Custom Cell]

My problem is about the description text. The description text can contain a lot of lines. The text length is not fixed.

How can I auto fix the height of the cell and the description text so text comes full in it..

I am using label for the description text. And I don't think it is the good option. What else should I use.?

Auto resize LAbel

[image: Label Resize]

Output

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: I am using a custom cell

Comment: you can change the height of cell as per test size ,and by the you achieve it

Answer (score 0):

You can get size of text [like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128797/calculating-uilabel-text-size), now change the frame of your description `UILable` and also change the cell height accordingly. You may need to apply constraints within your custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

[GET THE WORKING COPY HERE](https://github.com/souvickcse/AutoIncrementTableCell)

You have to do a few things for that
First: You have to change the height of the table cell with

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *text = [[arrComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:json_KEY_Comment];
    //THIS IS YOUR DESCRIPTION TEXT

    if(text)
    {
        CGFloat width = 249.0;//WIDTH OF THE DESCRIPTION TEXT
        UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];//FONT OF THE DESCRIPTION TEXT
        NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
        CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                                   options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                   context:nil];
        CGSize size = rect.size;
        size.height = ceilf(size.height);
        size.width  = ceilf(size.width);
        return size.height + 40;//HERE size.height IS THE HEIGHT OF THE DESCRIPTION TEXT AND 40 IS 
                                //HEADER TEXT AND IMAGE HEIGHT AND THE PADDING YOU WANT

    }
    else
    {
        return [tableView rowHeight];
    }
```

}

Second: Set the line no of the description text to 0 so it will automatically take the required no of lines[image: Screen Shot]

Third: Set the auto resizing of THE DESCRIPTION TEXT

[image: to this]

so it will automatically increase its height when the cell height changes[Note:if the label is in another view in the Cell Content View the parent of the label should also have the autoresizing set to this]
Thank You

Comment: It is not working. I getting a huge height of table cell. After the description text there is huge blank space between 1st and 2nd cell and so on

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please

Comment: Hi please check the SS

Comment: I guess the problem is though the cell height is increased but label height is not increasing

Comment: Have you provided proper font in the code ( [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];)

Comment: And can you check size.height with break point if it is increasing or not depending on different text for the label.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63160/discussion-between-souvickcse-and-shink).

Comment: You can use the source code from here https://github.com/souvickcse/AutoIncrementTableCell

Answer (score 0):

you can use the blow code to get the height of cell as per text height 
you have to pass one text and its font size and you will get result

```
-(CGFloat)getHeightOfText:(NSString *)text FontSize:(int)fontSize{


UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize];
NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){300, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
CGSize size = rect.size;
size.height = ceilf(size.height);
size.width  = ceilf(size.width);
NSLog(@"%f",size.height);
return size.height + 50;
}
```

After that in :

```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

return //call above method like [self getHeightOfText:text FontSize:fontSize];
 }
```

Comment: did you check that heightforRow ur geting height and also set the  frame of label in cell