# How to Compare 2 UiLabel's Width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have 2 UILabel in My TableView.
For E.g.

```
label1=@"Mihir";  
label2=@"Oza";
```

My Question is how to check which label's text width is bigger in dynamically not static? I mean how to compare two label's text width of?
Actually I want which label has bigger width of text.

Comment: Are you looking for such thing? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128797/calculating-uilabel-text-size

Comment: width or number of characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to compare the lenght of `UILabel` texts, rather than there size. Try following:

```
if (label1.text.length > label2.text.length) 
    NSLog(@"label1 text is longer");
else (label1.text.length < label2.text.length) 
    NSLog(@"label2 text is longer");
else // if they are of same length
    NSLog(@"Both labels' text lengths are equal.");
```

Answer (score 2):

Depend which approach would you like to use.

1. By number of characters
2. By width (irrespective of number of characters)

KKKK (4 K's) is **smaller** then iiiii (5 i's) if we compare by **length**

***BUT***

KKKK (4 K's) is **greater** then iiiii (5 i's) if we compare by width **after calling sizeToFit**.

Sample code as below.

### LabelCompareViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LabelCompareViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

### LabelCompareViewController.m

```
#import "LabelCompareViewController.h"

@interface LabelCompareViewController () {
    UILabel *label1;
    UILabel *label2;
    UILabel *label3;
    UILabel *label4;
}

@end

@implementation LabelCompareViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 40)];
    label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
    label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 300, 300, 40)];
    label4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 400, 300, 40)];

    label1.text = label2.text = label3.text = label4.text = @"";

    label1.textColor = label2.textColor = label3.textColor = label4.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [self.view addSubview:label1];
    [self.view addSubview:label2];
    [self.view addSubview:label3];
    [self.view addSubview:label4];


    label1.text = @"KKKK";
    label2.text = @"iiiii";

    NSString *op1 = @"Comparing Length : ";

    if (label1.text.length>label2.text.length) {
        op1 = [op1 stringByAppendingString:@"1>2"];
    } else if (label2.text.length>label1.text.length) {
        op1 = [op1 stringByAppendingString:@"2>1"];
    } else {
        op1 = [op1 stringByAppendingString:@"1==2"];
    }

    label3.text = op1;
    // gives output 2>1


    // after sizeToFit
    [label1 sizeToFit];
    [label2 sizeToFit];

    op1 = @"Comparing sizeToFit : ";

    if (label1.frame.size.width>label2.frame.size.width) {
        op1 = [op1 stringByAppendingString:@"1>2"];
    } else if (label2.frame.size.width>label1.frame.size.width) {
        op1 = [op1 stringByAppendingString:@"2>1"];
    } else {
        op1 = [op1 stringByAppendingString:@"1==2"];
    }

    label4.text = op1;
    // gives output 1>2

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you call `label1` and `label2` are actually *instances* of `NSString` and **not** `UILabel`. This is an important difference since `NSString` only represents the string datatype on iOS (a concatenation of characters) and `UILabel` on the other hand is a **UI Element** that has a `frame` with `width` and `height` and displays a `text` (of type `NSString`).

To me it looks like you just want to compare the `length` of the strings, not the `width` of a `UILabel`.

This you can do by using the `length` method of `NSString`.

```
if ([label1 length] < [label2 length]){
   NSLog(@"label2 is longer than label1");
}
else {
   NSLog(@"label1 is longer than label2");
}
```

If you actually want to compare the `width` of two instances of `UILabel` check @godomey's answer!

**Update:**
You have to be very careful *what* exactly you want to compare, from your question it doesn't become quite clear!

If you want to compare the **number of characters** that are displayed on each of the labels, then you will have to use:

```
if ([label1.text length] < [label2.text length]){
   NSLog(@"the text of label2 is longer than the one of label1");
}
else {
   NSLog(@"the text of label1 is longer than the one of label2");
}
```

If you want to use compare the **actual width (measured in *pixels*)** of the elements that are displayed on the UI, you need to use

```
if (label1.frame.size.width < label2.frame.size.width){
   NSLog(@"the width of label2 is greater than the one of label1");
}
else {
   NSLog(@"the width of label1 is greater than the one of label2");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank u for your answer but I am using uilabel in Uitableviewcell. and in this there is no length property available.

Comment: actually @Richa Sharma's answer is working fine for me.

Comment: then the code you showed in your question is wrong since `label1 = @"Mihir"` is of type `NSString`

Answer (score 0):

More shortly you can try like this:-

```
(label1.text.length > label2.text.length)?NSLog(@"label1 text is longer"): NSLog(@"label2 text is longer");
```