# ios uitextview auto font size

Tags: ios, fonts, uitextview

I want auto font size
Size `UITextView` want to change the font size is changed.

https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView

```
 if (self.ui_text.contentSize.height > self.ui_text.frame.size.height) {
    int fontIncrement = 1;
    while (self.ui_text.contentSize.height > self.ui_text.frame.size.height) {
        self.ui_text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:self.ui_text.font.pointSize - fontIncrement];
        fontIncrement++;   
    }
}else {
    int fontIncrement = 1;
    while (self.ui_text.contentSize.height >= self.ui_text.frame.size.height)    {
        self.ui_text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:8.0 + fontIncrement];
        fontIncrement++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the first sentence?

Comment: @AshokLondhe Did you mean to tag user1653467?

Comment: @user1653467 Please explain your question properly.

Comment: @user1766169  Yes. Sorry for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128797/calculating-uilabel-text-size