# Prevent a UILabel from truncating tail

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel

I have two `UILabel`s: **name** and **description**. The constraints are setup as the following:

- **name** has left and top constraint
- **description** has a right and top constraint
- A minimum 10 pixels spacing constraint between them so that they don't overlap

[image]

When I run the program, not consistently, sometimes **name** is truncated and sometimes **description** is truncated.

[image]
[image]

#### Question is: Is there a way to guarantee that when running out of space alway truncate the right label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to address this is to change the **Content Hugging Priority** for one of the labels. By default, this is set to 251. Just change one of the label's **Content Hugging Priority** to 250 or 252 depending on how you want it to be "hugged".

In [code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622485-setcontenthuggingpriority):

```
func setContentHuggingPriority(_ priority: UILayoutPriority, 
                              for axis: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis)
```

Or interface builder:

[image]

And check out this post if you need more info about this topic: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-content-hugging-and-content-compression-resistance-priorities-476fb5828ef

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a minimum width constraint for the left hand label (`lbl1`) then connecting the constraint to an IBOutlet in your `ViewController`.

Then on load or willAppear or any other related action, determine the minimum width of `lbl1` and set that to the constraints constant.

Then before the view appears, it should update the right hand label to the correct width without truncating the label on the left.

For reference of determining label size see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19128912/933887

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property in reducing font size is not the iss[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use `UILabel().adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` if you are okay with smaller font.