# Swift: how to set UITableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

In my `UITableViewController` I have many custom cells whose height depends on the length of the UITextView inside them. This means I cannot return a precise size from `heightForRowAtIndexPath()` method because I still don't know it at that point. Moreover, as I cannot create a `@IBOutlet weak var` to the constraint ruling the `UITextView`, here's the code I have tried:

```
let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BigTextCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BigTextCell

cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "icons/background.png")!)

cell.paragraph.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
cell.paragraph.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
cell.paragraph.editable = false
cell.title.enabled = false


switch (indexPath.row) {
  case 1:
        cell.title.text = "Chi è:"
        cell.icon.image = UIImage(named: "icons/field_fish.png")
        cell.paragraph.text = self.fieldsCollection["life_method"] as! String
        cell.paragraph.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "icons/quadretti.png")!)

        for constraint in cell.icon.constraints {
          if (constraint.identifier == "icon_width") {
            constraint.constant = 64.0
            break
          }
        }

        for constraint in cell.paragraph.constraints {
          if (constraint.identifier == "longTextConstraint") {
            constraint.constant = cell.paragraph.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: cell.paragraph.frame.width, height: CGFloat.max)).height
            break
          }
        }
...
```

Thus, the `UITextView` correctly sizes according to the length of the text but often the height of the cell is too much. How can I fix this?
Thank you

**UPDATE**
As some of you suggested, if I try this in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        //return 235.0
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BigTextCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BigTextCell
        cell.paragraph.text = self.fieldsCollection["life_method"] as! String

        for constraint in cell.paragraph.constraints {
            if (constraint.identifier == "longTextConstraint") {
                constraint.constant = cell.paragraph.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: cell.paragraph.frame.width, height: CGFloat.max)).height
                return constraint.constant+30.0
                break
            }
      }
}
```

the simulator **blocks**.

Answer (score 1):

You could set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` or calculate cell height for appropriate text in every `heightForRowAtIndexPath()` method call.

Comment: So, shall I have to repeat the same instructions I perform at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath `? Moreover if I use  `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` I get al the cells with the same height...

Comment: Do you really need UITextView? Could you use UILabel which could adjust size according to text? In your heightForRowAtIndexPath you should get text for current index path and calculate text height for it (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128797/calculating-uilabel-text-size)).

Comment: You need to return a meaningful value at `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` when using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, if you do and it still doesn't work, you should check the constraints. Keep in mind that using automatic dimension at a table view, while very convenient, is not free of bugs, be prepared and ready to use the older alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0 //Change this to any value
```

Comment: I am afraid it does not work because I get cells with all the same height which is very low...maybe my constraints are not correct but I don't know where to correct them...

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) return the exact height at `- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `- tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` (not necessarily the exact height here, but the closest the better, if the values are not precise enough you might get visual glitches and issues with autolayout if you are using it). The only thing missing for the calculation is a cell instance, you can either get it from the table view by calling the corresponding method cellForRowAtIndexPath or by using a static cell instance that you never display but use for calculation. The former is fast and easy to use, the latter has its own specific use cases, e.g. if you for some reason want to calculate the height that a cell would have without having an actual table view.

Note that even though `UITableView` and `UITableViewDataSource` have methods with similar signatures, `- cellForRowAtIndexPath` and 
`- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` respectively, they function differently and the method of table view can return `nil`, refer to the documentation for the details.

Comment: I have tried what you've written It does not work. I mean that I've tried to instantiate a cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath()` and then adjust the constraint of the `UITextView` according to the length and finally return something like `return constraint.constant+30.0` but the simulator blocks...

Comment: Don't dequeue a cell from inside of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`, that is a potential cause of an infinite recursion: iOS might want to call `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` whenever you dequeue a cell. In general, avoid unnecessary dependencies of some delegate methods on the other methods of the same delegate if the documentation doesn't directly state that you should. Try calling the table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead. Or manually init a single static instance of the cell class to be used only for calculations.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because it always dequeues a cell for each `indexPath.row`... I am trying to init a custom cell for calculations but I am not getting the right height...maybe because it lacks the constraints it would have in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call...