# Adding header to the tableview with dynamic heigh in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UIView(TableHeaderView) which has few labels and collection view. One of the label text is set on run time. So its height is unknown. I'm setting this view as the header for table view.

```
 let tableHeaderView = CommentsTableHeaderView.instanceFromNib() as! CommentsTableHeaderView
    commentsTable.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
```

In CommentsTableHeaderview class I have the following code.
I have set postDesc label's number of lines to 0. If the text comes in few lines, its cutting off. I want this to be dynamic and display all text.

```
class CommentsTableHeaderView: UIView,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var postDesc: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var profileName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var numberOfComments: UILabel!




class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {

    return UINib(nibName: "CommentsTableHeaderView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    imageCollectionView.delegate = self
    imageCollectionView.dataSource = self   
    imageCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "InnerCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "InnerCollectionCell")
    postDesc.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    postDesc.numberOfLines = 0
    postDesc.text = "hi"



}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("inside collection view")

    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print("inside cell")
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InnerCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! InnerCollectionCell

    cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Recipe.jpeg")

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
    print("inside size\(collectionView.frame.width)")

    return CGSize(width: imageCollectionView.frame.width, height: 200)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
}
```

}
[image: Please see the constraints Image]

Comment: where is your constraints? or Auto resizing mask?

Comment: I have set the constraints in xib file

Comment: check your constraints . are you using height contraints for that label?

Comment: post screen shot if possible

Comment: Set the estimated row height ? Assuming you have set the row height as automatic dimension

Comment: @Ram no I have not set the height constraint for label

Comment: @user1046037  but I want the row height to be dynamic too .

Comment: @SPatel Please see the constraint screen shot here https://imgur.com/a/TKkVfgt

Comment: Automatic dimension will determine the height based on auto layout but you need to give a rough estimate for performance reasons

Comment: @user1046037 but I’m adding a Uivew to table header, not to the section . How does tow height impact on this . All my table cells are displaying properly .

Comment: @ Pruthvi Hariharan i guess   you are setting top and bottom constraints also try to remove bottom constraints for label and run it.

Comment: @Ram  without top and bottom constraint , how will it know where it has to be placed? It gives error for y position

Comment: My bad I misread the question thought it was cell. I suppose you are referring to the header

Comment: @Pruthvi Hariharan dont use bottom constraints ... use top leading and trailing constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to [resize your UILabel according to the text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128797/calculating-uilabel-text-size). Do not put height constraints on UILabel. Rather pin its bottom to the bottom view's top.

Do that programmatic resizing after `viewDidLoad()` - maybe in `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidAppear()`, before you do your first `reloadData()` call.

Here is a [nice tutorial](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/variable-height-table-view-header/) how this should be done - it suggests doing the resizing inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, which should also be fine.

Comment: override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        guard let headerView = commentsTable.tableHeaderView else {
            return
        }
        print("headerView height \(headerView.frame.height)")
        let size = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
        print("size is \(size.height)")
        if headerView.frame.size.height != size.height {
            headerView.frame.size.height = size.height
            commentsTable.tableHeaderView = headerView
           commentsTable.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

Comment: I have added above func. But the label is displaying in only one line. Rest text is cutting off.

Comment: Is the tableview plain or grouped? Also there is no label resize code in your viewDidLayoutSubviews().

Comment: Table view is plain not grouped .  But in that tutorial , they haven’t not asked for label resize code.

Comment: Try one of the solutions to resize your label as well - like the link given from SO, combined with the tutorial stuff. And also try the grouped table view.

Comment: Finally it Worked! I added the above mentioned viewDidLayoutSubviews func and also I set the preferred max width of label to some constant.

Comment: Nice to know. If it helped, mark as correct / upvote when you get chance.

Answer (score 0):

you need 2 collectionViewDelegate methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: x, height: x)
}
```

if you wish to have a dynamic height in referenceSizeForHeaderInSection height field, set your height according to screen size for ex, UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.09