# Swift: Programmatically make UILabel bold without changing its size?

Tags: swift, uilabel, bold

I have a UILabel created programmatically. I would like to make the text of the label bold without specifying font size. So far I have only found:

```
UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: CGFloat)
```

This is what I have exactly:

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
let fontSize: CGFloat = 26
titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: titleLabelFontSize)
```

But this way I am also setting the size. I would like to avoid that. Is there a way?

If there is no way, what would be a good workaround in Swift?

Thank you!

Comment: Something like that: `titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: titleLabel.font.pointSize)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set bold and italic on UILabel of iPhone/iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713236/how-do-i-set-bold-and-italic-on-uilabel-of-iphone-ipad)

Comment: This may help: [How can I get the font size and font name of a UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866138/how-can-i-get-the-font-size-and-font-name-of-a-uilabel)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Why not just:

```
titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: titleLabel.font.pointSize)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great!

Comment: Thanks Works for me.

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: If I could upvote 100 times, I would. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

To just make the Font bold without altering the font size you could create an extension like this (which is based off the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713236/how-do-i-set-bold-and-italic-on-uilabel-of-iphone-ipad):

```
extension UIFont {

    func withTraits(traits:UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits...) -> UIFont {
        let descriptor = self.fontDescriptor()
        .fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(traits))
        return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: 0)
    }

    func bold() -> UIFont {
        return withTraits(.TraitBold)
    }

}
```

So that way you could use it like this:

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.font = titleLabel.font.bold() //no need to include size!
```

**Update for Swift 4 syntax:**

```
extension UIFont {

    func withTraits(traits:UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits...) -> UIFont {
        let descriptor = self.fontDescriptor               
           .withSymbolicTraits(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(traits))
        return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor!, size: 0)
    }

    func bold() -> UIFont {
        return withTraits(traits: .traitBold)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I went with a different answer but I've learned from your post.